# Irreducible module over upper triangular matrices

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules, noncommutative-algebra

Let $R$ be a ring and $M$ be an irreducible $R$ module. I want to create an irreducible $A$-module, where

$$A = \begin{pmatrix}R & R\\0 & R\end{pmatrix}.$$

I defined $\bar{M}$ as
$$\bar{M} = \{(m, 0) : m \in M\}.$$

$\bar{M}$ is an $A$-module in the natural way. So let $J$ be a $A$-submodule of $\bar{M}$. Then,
$$J\begin{pmatrix}R & R\\0 & R\end{pmatrix} \subseteq J.$$

Let $p\in J$. Since $J\subset\bar{M}$, $p=(m,0)$, where $m \in M$. Thus
$$p\begin{pmatrix}R & R\\0 & R\end{pmatrix} = (m,0)\begin{pmatrix}R & R\\0 & R\end{pmatrix} = (mR,0).$$

Now, since $M$ is an irreducible $R$-module, and $m\not=0$, $mR=M$ (**is it true that $mR\not=(0)$?**). We show that
$$p\begin{pmatrix}R & R\\0 & R\end{pmatrix} = (M,0) = \bar{M}.$$

This implies that
$$\bar{M} = p\begin{pmatrix}R & R\\0 & R\end{pmatrix} \subseteq J \subseteq \bar{M} \implies J = \bar{M}.$$

So, $\bar{M}$ is an irreducible $A$-module. Is this proof correct?

Comment: I think that there is a problem with the definition of $\bar{M}$. If we treat its elements as  $1 \times 2$-matrices, then it is not actually a right $A$-module under the obvious definition of scalar multiplication. Instead, it should be defined as $\{(0, m): m \in M\}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof is correct, except for one small mistake.

If $M \times M$ is considered as a right $A$-module using the obvious definition of scalar multiplication (i.e., $\begin{pmatrix}m&n\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}a&b\\0&c\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}ma&mb+nc\end{pmatrix}$), then $M \times \{0\}$ is not a submodule, but $\{0\} \times M$ is a submodule. So, $\bar{M}$ should actually be defined as $\{0\} \times M$, not as $M \times \{0\}$.

Is it true that $mR \ne (0)$? Of course, it is true (assuming that $R$ is a unital ring and $M$ is a unital right $R$-module), since $0 \ne m = m1 \in mR$.

If rings and modules are not required to be unital, then $mR$ could be zero for some nonzero $m \in M$. For example, $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ with the trivial zero scalar multiplication would be an irreducible $R$-module for any prime $p$, and then $mR=(0)$ for every $m \in \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$.

Other than $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ for prime $p$ with the trivial zero scalar multiplication, there are no other counterexamples (up to isomorphism) in the nonunital case. Indeed, $\{m \in M : mR = (0)\}$ is easily seen to be a submodule of $M$, and so by irreducibility, it must be either $(0)$ or $M$. If it is $M$, then $M$ would have the trivial zero scalar multiplication and the submodules of $M$ would then just be the additive subgroups. The irreducible abelian groups (or $\mathbb{Z}$-modules) up to isomorphism are known to be just $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ for prime $p$, so $M$ must be isomorphic to one of them.

In the $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ case, $\bar{M}$ would still be isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ with the trivial zero scalar multiplication, so it would still be an irreducible $A$-module.

Comment: Thank you, Geoffrey! I will correct the mistakes as you pointed.

Comment: Did you agre that $mR \not=(0)$? I know that $m\not=0$, but if $R$ doesn't have unit I don't know how to prove that $mR\not=(0)$.

Comment: Please see my updated answer for why $mR \ne (0)$. The default convention should be to assume that rings are unital.

Comment: But Herstein in Non-commutative Rings book does not make this assumption. So, if $1 \not \in R$, this proof will not work (at least I think).

Comment: I have updated my answer to include the details in the nonunital case.